# How to alter all the columns of a specific data type on a single table

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

This is in regards to a PostgreSQL database. I would like to change all of the columns that are currently `character varying` to `text` on a single table. I'm looking for a query that could make this happen quickly.

Comment: What about the manual? ALTER TABLE.... VARCHAR (without a constraint on the length) and TEXT are the same, don't bother about the name.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66387/change-column-type-from-varchar-to-text-in-all-tables-at-once